# How to edit options in a google visualisation data table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, google-visualization, datatables

I use the following [API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visdraw) to load my data into my timeline.

I set options to my datatable using an object as follows:

```
var options = {
    "width":  "100%",
    "height": "300px",
    "editable": true,
    "style": "box",
    "min":  min_boundary,              
    "zoomMin": 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,        
    "zoomMax": 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 3
};
```

and apply these using the method draw():

```
timeline.draw(data, options);
```

The problem i'm having is how to edit these options once the table has been drawn. From my user input, I want to be able to change the minimum and maximum boundary.

I believe I must use a listener, am I right?

How can I change these values and re-apply them?

Thanks

Comment: Just create new `options` object and call `timeline.draw(data, options);` again.

Comment: Just in a separate function? No listener?

Comment: You're probably better off redrawing the existing chart object rather than creating a new one.  You may want to use an event handler bound to some HTML element to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

Simply made a function to recreate the functions array and recalled the method

```
timeline.draw(date,options)
```